# Spring-data-elasticsearch @JsonProperty not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jackson, spring-data

I am using Spring-data-elasticsearch with Spring Boot and I try to receive/send data to elasticsearch using ElasticsearchRepository.
I can read (`GET`) documents and transform it into java objects without issue, but I cannot save (`POST`) documents due to one thing : I am using `@JsonProperty` for one of my property.
I tried to save data without it and it worked, but the issue is that the property names would mismatch.

The property I want to use `@JsonProperty` on is named `someProperty` in my java program and `some-property` inside the 'elasticsearch' DB.

My class looks like this :

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
@JsonProperty("some-property")
private SomeProperty someProperty;
```

Comment: Which version of ElasticSearch do you use? If higher than 6.2.2 then be aware of that Spring Data ElasticSearch doesn't support it.

Comment: I missed that! I'm using ES 6.5.0 that must be the reason. I changed my mind and will use the rest client for java provided by ES. thanks.

Comment: @Ice is there any alternative?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of any other solution. Ofc there is possibility to extend library, but then you have to support it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and found out that it is problem with setter.
Adding setter like this will solve the problem

```
public void setSome-property(SomeProperty someProperty) {
    this.someProperty = someProperty;
}
```